# Bool variable doesn't update its status

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a problem... I create a Parent (EmptyGameObject) and its child (imported 3d model). The child object has a bool variable that change if it collide with an obstacle (tag "Obstacle"). I create a script for the Parent that load the bool variable  `VariabileBool classTest = cubo.GetComponentInChildren<VariabileBool>();` but there's a problem... The value of bool variable, don't update when in the children script change is status (become true)... How can I resolve this problem? Sorry for my bad English...

**VariabileBool script (on Child object):**

```
public class VariabileBool : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool variabile = true;
}
```

**Parent script for read the variable:**

```
public class LettoreVariabile : MonoBehaviour
{
    VariabileBool classeVariabile;
    public GameObject cube;
    private void Start()
    {
        classeVariabile = cube.GetComponentInChildren<VariabileBool>();
    }
    void Update()
    {

        Debug.Log(classeVariabile.variabile);
    }
}
```

[image: img]

I tried to update the status of bool in `Void Start()`, but doesn't work...
once the variable has taken a state, it does not change...

Comment: you have not shown any code that changes the value of variabile

Comment: No, because if I change the variabile value (via script), the value load on the "second script" doesn't update

Comment: But we can’t recreate it with what you have shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to access VariabileBool object from another object with this way;

- create an empty VariableBoolObject in your scene.
- Attach VariableBool class to the VariableBoolObject. (simple drag and drop process)
- create second empty lettoVariable object in your scene. Then attach lettoVariable script to this object.
- Then, open your scene select LettoreVariabile in your scene hierarchy. Drag and drop VariableBoolObject to LettoreVariabile's classeVariabile area in the inspector.

  - You can access the bool variable of other object with this way.

I hope this is the answer you search. Have a nice day.

---

```
 public class LettoreVariabile : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public VariabileBool classeVariabile;

     void Update()
     {
         Debug.Log(classeVariabile. variabile);
     }
 }
```